# How to use calculated fields to create a hyperlink in Community Connectors

Tags: google-apps-script, looker-studio

I'm building a custom Community Connector for Google Data Studio, and I'm running into trouble trying to create a hyperlink field.

I have been able to manually create a [HYPERLINK field](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7431836?ref_topic=7041728) through the GDS dashboard, but I want to have the Hyperlink field built into my connector, rather than need to be manually created.

```
fields.newDimension()
    .setId('Hyperlink')
    .setType(types.URL)
    .setFormula('HYPERLINK($IssueURL,$IssueKey)');
```

It should take the $IssueURL and create a hyperlink to it with the link text being the $IssueKey, however it just appends the $IssueKey in front of the $IssueURL and try's to make a link to that (Ex: IssueKeyhttps://www.mywebsite.com).

Comment: Could you add a link to your script & share it with view access. Without seeing the entire `getSchema()` function, it's hard to guess what might be going wrong.

Comment: [Here](https://script.google.com/d/1tbzHuUvhetUZGO6mhnM0AWp8Z5aX2fqNFMFcMncgvKEo4AunW3vzMcA9/edit?usp=sharing) is a link to the `getSchema()` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update 4-10-2019**

You can now use the `HYPERLINK`, `IMAGE`, `IMAGE_LINK` types for formula fields. Instead of the workaround, do the following:

```
fields.newDimension()
    .setId('Hyperlink')
    .setType(types.HYPERLINK)
    .setFormula('HYPERLINK($IssueURL,$IssueKey)');
```

---

**original workaround**

This is a bug caused to a missing fieldType. The type for a a hyperlink should be `types.HYPERLINK`, but that type isn't currently available. I will work on getting that type into the `DataStudioApp` object.

For the time being, you can use this workaround:

```
function getSchema(request) {
  var fields = getFields().build();
  fields.forEach(function (field) {
    // You need to change 'Hyperlink' to whatever id you set for your hyperlink formula field. 
    if (field.name === 'Hyperlink') {
      field.semantics.semanticType = 'HYPERLINK';
    }
  });
  return { schema: fields };
}
```